# How to get eigen values for the sklearn.decomposition.PCA analysis?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Could you help me to get sorted (high to low) eigen values for my data while using the sklearn.decomposition.PCA module?

```
all_samples=some data array
sklearn_pca = sklearnPCA(n_components=2)
sklearn_transf = sklearn_pca.fit_transform(all_samples.T)
```

`print sklearn_transf` gives the transformed eigen vectors but not the eigen values.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues are stored in

```
sklearn_pca.explained_variance_
```

Normalized eigenvalues constitute the explained variance ratio:

```
sklearn_pca.explained_variance_ratio_
```